# Alternative for "deep in my heart"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a colloquial conversatiostion or maybe in a poetic work may one of the expressions below be used in place of "deep in my heart" and still keeping the same meaning?

All the wonderful moments we spent together still **live deep in here**.

All the wonderful moments we spent together still live **deep down here**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using gestures to show that "here" mean "my heart", if you change "heart" to "here" you will change the meaning.

"Heart" is quite specific. "Here" could be any place from the context.